# How to obtain references to Futures of a scheduledThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: java, concurrency, timeout, executorservice, executor

I have a scheduled executor service and I require the Futures returned after tasks are scheduled. The Javadoc says that a ScheduledFuture is returned after scheduling a task - however, how can I obtain subsequent Futures of yet to be run tasks?

My call looks like the following: 
**exec.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Task(), 0, interval, TimeUnit.MINUTES);**

New tasks are indeed submitted and run, however I only have a future for the first time that the call is made. Is this Future something that is reused or is reusable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the same Future for all the executions.  cancelling it cancels the current and all future executions.

Comment: Interesting, so how do I know if one execution has completed and when the next starts? Basically how to reuse the future effectively?

Comment: @pk11 - is there something specific you are trying to determine?  there is a `getDelay` method on the ScheduledFuture.

Comment: more so I am interested in the value that the ScheduledFuture returns every time it runs.

Comment: @pk11 - the Future for a repeating task doesn't return anything.